# Where can I get 5000+ classified images of zoo animals?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, classification, dataset

please help! We are college students doing this for a project. The project is using neural networks and want to build a model that takes in an input of a colored image of an animal and outputs the name of the animal. We are hoping to use some basic optimizations such as L2 regularization and batch norm, but the goal of the project is for people to get the basics of neural networks and put a simple project. We are looking for 5000+ classified images of animals from zoos that are colored and requires no use of GPUs (so no one picture should be 1024 x 1024 pixels, for example, because that would take too much memory). Also, because we are at the beginning stage of learning neural network, we are thinking that the number of animal categories is less than 15 or so. We looked at Kaggle and found sea animal pictures, but because the sea animal pictures probably would be harder to classify due to blue colors, we were hoping to get land animal pictures (or at least more variety / easier to classify animal pictures). Do you know where to get the pictures we are looking for? Also, where can we learn the codes for data augmentation for image processing (stretching, rotating, etc.)?

Comment: [This](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) might be a more appropriate venue to post your inquiry.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at Roboflow datasets (ex. https://universe.roboflow.com/praveen-rp1yb/animal-v8mvl/dataset/1, although this is image detection), although I would highly recommend that you examine the quality of the images beforehand.

If you want a quick-and-dirty way to do data augmentation, Roboflow can do that for you natively (although only up to 3 times augmentation). Otherwise, you should probably find a Github for that.